# Является ли GLUT многозадачной?

Tags: glut, c++, opengl

Изучаю библиотеку GLUT. Создаётся впечатление, что в GLUT отрисовка и события работают параллельно, создавая многозадачность?

Comment: @sitev_ru, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Нет, в GLUT отрисовка и события не параллельны, в каждый момент времени работает что-то одно.

Answer (score 1):

[[@sitev_ru](/users/18326/sitev_ru)](/users/18326/sitev_ru), а причем здесь многозадачность в этой библиотеке. Многозадачность обеспечивается операционной системой, и, скорей всего, вы не под DOS пишете. Если это так, то операционная система обеспечивает выделение времени по очереди всем запущенным приложениям и их потокам в текущее время - это и является многозадачностью. glut всего лишь обеспечивает кросплатформенный [ввод и вывод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLUT) в/из приложения.